# Google+ Hangout API chatbot

Tags: google-plus, chatbot, google-hangouts

I am trying to build a chatbot on Google Hangout Chat. Per the documentation, the API is no longer supported:

https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.data

Are we still able to subscribe to receive messages from a user and send a response?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need a g suite account in order to enable the hangout API chat